# Why can I not return a list of users on my page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This code is supposed to output the users that I have created using Identity. It will output the native attributes to  identity such as email, but for some reason it will not output the date that the password was last changed. I physically see the attribute in my database and was able to input it using the form no problem, but I cannot get it out using `IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>`. How do I get around this?

```
 @model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>
    @using PagedList.Mvc;
    <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Manage Users";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ManageUsers", "AdminTools", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 section-padding section-top-padding white-background">
            <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Password Change Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.passwordLastChanged)</td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="buttonIcon dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CreateUserModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign fa-lg"> </span>New User</button>

    </div>
}
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateUserModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        @Html.Action("Register", "Account")
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have error ?

Comment: yes! My bad... I'm a dummy...'Identityuser' does nto contain a definition for 'passwordLastChanged' and no extension method 'passwordLastChanged' accepting a first argument type...... kind of the standard DNE error.

Comment: @TravisTubbs is the property present in the entity?

Comment: Yes? I am not sure how it is working in the background, but in class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, I do have the value there, and it is in the ASPNETUSER table in my database.

Comment: Use ApplicationUser instead of IdentityUser as your model class